# Boto ec2 creating disk takes a long time to be created - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm writing a proof of concept about using `boto` to create, attach, detach and destroy EBS volumes in EC2:

```
import time
import ec2.boto

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2",
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY)

reservation = conn.run_instances(
                'ami-1fa78f2f',
                instance_type='m3.medium')

instance = reservation.instances[0]
instance.add_tag('Name', 'volume_test')


while instance.state != 'running':
        time.sleep(10)
        instance.update() # Updates Instance metadata
        print 'Instance state: ', instance.state

print "attempting to attach volume"
vol = conn.create_volume(10, instance.placement)
while vol.status != 'available':
        print 'Vol state: ', vol.status
        time.sleep(20)

vol.attach(instance.id, '/dev/sdh')
```

It's a 10GBv volume, however it never gets out of the 'creating' state:

```
# python test.py 
Instance state:  pending
Instance state:  pending
Instance state:  running
attempting to attach volume
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
Vol state:  creating
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is EC2 too slow to create a volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the volume inside the loop.  Try this.

```
print "attempting to attach volume"
vol = conn.create_volume(10, instance.placement)
while vol.status != 'available':
    print 'Vol state: ', vol.status
    time.sleep(20)
    vol.update()
```

Comment: For those coming from Google: `vol.status` is now `vol.state` and `vol.update` is now `vol.reload`.